# How to make an operation in command prompt in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have two files - user.js and dataserver.js.

The dataserver.js contains this express.js and node.js API:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
var quotes = [];

app.get('/quote', function(req, res) {
  var q = quotes[req.params.id];
  res.json(q);
});

app.post('/quote', function(req, res) {
  var newQuote = {
    author : req.body.author,
    text : req.body.text
  };

  quotes.push(newQuote);
  res.json(true);
});
```

What I want is to have a command line run time input in command prompt like this after running user.js in node.js

```
/********
Enter Operation
[1] Show All Quotes
[2] Add Quotes
[3] Exit
*/
```

Comment: So while the server is running you want to be able to enter things in the command line? If so I wouldn't call it "command line arguments" because that refers to arguments passed to the program when it is invoked on the command line. Probably more like command line run time input, kind of like a REPL.

Comment: @ElliotE yes. What should be the correct term?

Comment: Shell prompt / Command line prompt / Command line input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to output a message and then use the below module to prompt the user for input on one of the options.

Try the below module for handling shell prompts.

```
$ npm install prompt
```

https://github.com/flatiron/prompt

Comment: Interesting. In my case how would I able to do it for the GET and POST?

Comment: So why are you wanting to connect a prompt input to an express API endpoint? Is someone going to be setting at a machine answering calls from users browsers?

Comment: The Shell prompt should be able to output the GET method and POST from the dataserver.js method to the Shell prompt.

Comment: I think you might be a bit confused. Express is meant to be used for creating a web server to listen for HTTP calls from a browser or other system through a network API. It wouldn't directly interface with your shell. If you wanted to do that you would use something like prompt to directly call the function you want to run and not go through express at all.

Comment: So the way to prompt for another entry and call the POST method is not possible via shell script? but what if I convert the input from the shell to JSON string then call the POST method from dataserver.js?

Comment: Ideally you should setup dataserver.js to push the quotes into a datastore such as a database or file and then use users.js to retrieve quotes from that datastore. Don't try to combine both into one app you should consider each one a separate node app. If you do that then you can write users.js to take an input using prompt and then call a function to retrieve the stored quotes from the datastore.